# Deleting folders in databricks without db.utils

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks

How to delete a directory in Databricks while using Pyspark (without using `db.utils`)?

I want to try it using `%fs`.

I would also like to know if we can delete the files along with the folders using `%fs`?

Comment: I removed the part about "what other `%fs` commands are there"; we require one question per question and this seems like an obvious RTFM anyway.

Comment: I never used `databrick` but I suspect that `%fs`  is shorter version of `dbutils.fs` See: [Work with files on Databricks](https://docs.databricks.com/en/files/index.html#work-with-files-in-cloud-object-storage)

Comment: To delete file along with folders using `%fs`, you can use `%fs rm -r -f /path/`

Comment: @ShantanuTripathi Please post solutions as answers, not comments.